# Cordova-Plugin-Firebase when app goes from OFF to ACTIVE, onNotificationOpen() does not work on Android

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented the Cordova-Plugin-Firebase in an Ionic2 project on an Android device.

I followed the guidelines and it works. About the function onNotificationOpen(), as it is explained in the [doc of the plugin](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase#onnotificationopen):

> App is in background:
>
> - User receives the notification message in its device notification bar
> - User taps the notification and the app opens
> - User receives the notification data in the JavaScript callback

If the app is closed (not in the background), if I send a Push Notification, it does:

> - User receives the notification message in its device notification bar

Then I tap the notification in the panel that shows all the notifications, the app loads up and opens.

If the app is in background, the following function would trigger some events as the app takes the foreground of the screen:

```
Firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe(
       (res) => { console.info(res)},
       (err) => { console.info(err)},
       () => {console.log("completed)}
);
```

But **when the app is OFF**, it seems that this function, above, is not set up to run at the opening of the app. Hence it **does not catch that the app had been opened thru a tap of a notification** displayed in the notifications panel board.

Is this normal: If yes, is there as documentation explaining why somewhere; And would there be another way to **detect through an event** that a **notification message** has been **tapped to open** the **app from OFF to ACTIVE**? If not, would one have an idea of what could be my mistake?

Comment: By OFF you mean "App not running even in background", correct?

Comment: You've understood correctly what I meant: App  is not running at all and the user tap on a push notification message linked to the app and that starts the app, and bring it to foreground.

Comment: i'm encountering the same problem. I'm searching from 3-days about this problem. Currently we have a forked cordova-firebase-plugin installed in our cordova/ionic app by npm. Maybe a solution is update forked plugin :( 
i know ... i'd like that the solution be a server push field but we're just tried all field in documentation reported https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options or here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref. Official plugin documentation is very **MINIMAL**

Answer (score 0):

A push notification (like a deeplink) has to be handled somewhere within your own code - Somewhere you need to decide what activity the notification opens and what happens in that case. Thus you can't defer it to Firebase to detect this for you.

When the app was dead, clicking the push notification will send an Intent with the received data to your app. That is the intent where you can handle it (for example in onStart/Resume()). If you were to log the intent available when your app launches from notification you'll see it contains something similar the following:

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.my.package cmp=com.my.package/.MyMainActivity (has extras) }
Extras { 
   google.sent_time > 1490275998196, 
   from > 9994599943, 
   google.message_id > 0:14902799999965%346177c211bbbb7c2, 
   collapse_key > com.my.package 
}
```

This means you can do something like

```
if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    //identify whether this was a push notification intent
    if (getIntent().getExtras().get("google.message_id") != null) { 
        //Here you can do the same things you do when opened from background
        console.log("completed"");
    }
}
```

Comment: this is native android.. OP is asking about ionic 2

Comment: Well if you think there is an Ionic-only answer, I'd like to see you post it. That's better than adding comments with no value.